# How can the accuracy of the dictionary-based approach be measured and improved?

Tags: python, sentiment-analysis

I recently used TextBlob and the NLTK library to do sentiment analysis. I used both dictionary-based and machine learning-based approaches. It is relatively easy to measure accuracy when we use machine learning approach, just define a test set. The same goes for improving accuracy, just modify the training set.

But what about dictionary-based approaches instead? How do you **measure** and **improve** their accuracy?

Comment: As long as the dictionary-based approaches give the same kind of result as the machine learning approach (e.g. positive/negative/neutral), the same accuracy evaluation should be applicable to both. Why do you think the same accuracy evaluation is not applicable for dictionary-based approaches?

Comment: Maybe I was wrong. So how do I measure accuracy on dictionary-based approaches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Evaluation is always based on the task, not on the method. Since the dictionary-based method gives an output similar to the ML-based approach, you can evaluate it in the same way, using a test set with gold-standard labels (preferably the same test set as the other method, or at least similar in size).

Maybe what confuses you is that the dictionary-based method doesn't require training so you there's no need for splitting the data between training and test set.

Note: the dictionary-based approach is a [heuristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heuristic) method.

Comment: Thanks you! And what about the improving?

Comment: @zcbcpaoa it depends if there are any parameters for the dictionary-based method which can be modified, but otherwise it's simply not possible to improve its performance. Note that the dictionary-based method is equivalent to a single model which has already been trained, it's not like a ML method which has multiple options and can produce many different models.

Comment: [Why is dictionary-based approach a heuristic method?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/126759/119882)